# Get a 'clear' error message in Lua

Tags: error-handling, lua

I am using the `error` function in quite a few of my functions and would like to propagate the error messages to the user. However, I obviously don't want to include information about **where** the error occured exactly; this information should only go to the log files.

For example, I have a class that manages the connection to a server. If the connection times out, it calls

```
error("Connection timed out!")
```

The error message is then caught by the calling code via `pcall`. However, the message contains not only the message I passed, but also the name of the file that caused the error and the line number:

```
common/net/enetclient.lua:21: Connection timed out!
```

The question is: Is there any way to only retrieve the error message itself, or do I have to do this manually like following:

```
local status, msg = pcall(someFunctionThatThrowsErrors)
if not status then
    local file, msg = msg:match("(.-:%d+): (.+)")
    print("Error: " .. msg)
end
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation of the [`error` function](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-error):

> #### `error (message [, level])`
>
> Terminates the last protected function called and returns `message` as the error message. Function `error` never returns.
>
> Usually, `error` adds some information about the error position at the beginning of the message, if the message is a string. The `level` argument specifies how to get the error position. With level 1 (the default), the error position is where the `error` function was called. Level 2 points the error to where the function that called `error` was called; and so on. Passing a level 0 avoids the addition of error position information to the message.

From what is stated in the second paragraph, adding a level of `0` to the `error` call will result in the desired output:

```
error("Connection timed out!", 0)
```

Comment: Huh, wouldn't have expected to work this way... Alright. Btw: you wrote that adding level `2` would result in the desired output, but it is level `0` ;) However, this solved my problem :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: But what do you do in the case of `assert()`, which doesn't include a `level` argument? And what about errors from builtin functions that raise their own exceptions, so you can't specify a `level` at all?